# Extract Values from JSON Response in Scala

Tags: json, scala

How could I extract values from the following response:

```
 {"photosets":{"cancreate":1, "page":1, "pages":1, "perpage":1, "total":1, "photoset":
[{"id":"72157629171255321", "primary":"6817523143", "secret":"250f42ed7c", "server":"7166", 
"farm":8, "photos":"1", "videos":0, "title":{"_content":"Set1"}, "description":{"_content":""}, 
"needs_interstitial":0, "visibility_can_see_set":1, "count_views":"0", "count_comments":"0", 
"can_comment":1, "date_create":"1328373127", "date_update":"1328373159"}]}, "stat":"ok"}
```

I need some values not All of them for example I need "id" field How can I get it?

Thanks,

Comment: Any solution Using lift-json, dispatch or sjson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very performant wrapper (because Jackson is...) for scala.
Jerkson will help you in doing this [check this out](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson).

```
val ids: Seq[JString] = parse[JValue]("""
  {"photosets":{"cancreate":1, "page":1, "pages":1, "perpage":1, "total":1, "photoset":
  [{"id":"72157629171255321", "primary":"6817523143", "secret":"250f42ed7c", "server":"7166", "farm":8, "photos":"1", "videos":0, "title":{"_content":"Set1"}, "description": {"_content":""}, "needs_interstitial":0, "visibility_can_see_set":1, "count_views":"0", "count_comments":"0", "can_comment":1, "date_create":"1328373127", "date_update":"1328373159"}]}, "stat":"ok"}
""") \\ "id"
```

Here is a HowTo, note the use of `parse` that will return a `JValue`, on which you can call `\` or `\\` that find on the first level or any the property given rigth after.

Using reflection, Jerkson is also available to parse directly in case class, check the documentation... it's very powerful

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything inherently Scala about this, just use a JSON parser like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and extract the information that you need.

Comment: It is not important to be part of Scala.